# OAuth 2.0 sample DotNetOpenAuth for AuthorizationServer

Tags: .net, oauth-2.0, sample

I have been struggling to route requests to OAuthController using routes.MapRoute without success.

In theory following should have worked:

```
    routes.MapRoute(
        "OAuth", // Route name
        "oauth/authorize/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "OAuth", action = "Authorize", id = String.Empty});
```

Appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: what have you been struggling with? what is the error you are getting? what is the rest of the configuration? What framework are you using for OAuth if any? You would have reformulate your question.

Comment: I took the sample from DotNetOpenAuth\branches\v5.0\samples in GitHub. The sample itself is build over OpenID sample. I wanted to get rid of OpenID related stuff for my own OAuth 2.0 implementation. In that process, I ended up with messed up routemap.  I found a much simpler .NET implementation at https://github.com/ErikSchierboom/basicoauth2server.persistent and decided to use it.

Comment: BTW, the sample expects a openID after you press "Request Authorization" button. If I give a openID it keeps failing on c:\Source\DotNetOpenAuth\branches\v5.0\src\DotNetOpenAuth.OpenId.RelyingParty\OpenId\RelyingParty\OpenIdRelyingParty.cs    Line: 343. Any sample openID that will work will be helpful.